# Как найти таблицу в phpmyadmin, для элементов нужной страницы через браузер?

Tags: phpmyadmin, google-chrome-devtools

Всем привет! Для меня сейчас важно находить таблицы phpmyadmin для некоторых данных на страницах сайта. Захожу значит, в phpmyadmin а там лес непонятных таблиц, как же сделать так чтобы через браузер, просмотреть код элемента, и там же узнать в какой таблице он лежит? И вообще возможно ли это? Использую я Google Chrome

Answer (score -1):

Нужен написать php script, чтобы из базы выберал нужные элементы и показал, если работайте на компьютеру без сервера нужен Вам сервер например опен сервер для локального работы, за акцент извините ))

Comment: Спасибо, большое)